# Policy to upgrade OS images in Google GCE

Tags: google-compute-engine

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/image-management-best-practices isn't helpful.

Should I recreate infrastructure from new images or `sudo apt dist-upgrade`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your images are Linux based the answer is: you can use `sudo apt dist-upgrade`.

Check https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#debian for description what Google's engineers are altered in Debian.

All alterations are done via packages [`google-compute-engine` & `python-google-compute-engine`](https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/google-compute-engine-buster/main/binary-amd64/Packages) those are preinstalled and available via `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud.list`:

```
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-stretch main
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-compute-engine-stretch-stable main
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-stretch main
```

Before `dist-upgrade` you need to alter `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud.list` and change occurrences of `stretch` to `buster`.

With kernel updates you need to reboot VM.